# High value weeds or plants that can replace the chemical treatment of pesticides and herbicides?

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, pest-control, plant-recommendations

I'm working on a project that aims to replace (at least lower) the use of chemical pesticides and herbicides in farming with the use of high value weeds and plants that can naturally replace the chemical treatment.  So for example , if hedgerows (the edges of the field or the surrounding of a crop) made with high value weeds can be incorporated to fixate nitrogen,  or to help fight and resist a given disease, or maybe have a positive impact on the crop, etc...

My mission is : to build a database with high value weeds and plants, and their effects. For example the database should look like :

| High value weed | effect |
| --- | --- |
| x | fixate nitrogen |
| y | help crop fight disease d |
| z | effect z |

I'm looking for any already existing database, research or any resource that tackle something like this.
Note : I'm not an expert in farming , I'm just a data science student dealing with agriculture related problems. So please forgive my ignorance. I would be very happy to learn.

Comment: Does "High Value Weed" mean something specific?  "Weed" usually means any plant without 'value'.  Or cannabis.  I think 'cover crops' would cover a subset of what you're looking for, and they are well documented for agriculture purposes.  Here is one example of a database of cover crops. https://sarep.ucdavis.edu/covercrop

Comment: Fixing nitrogen in a hedgerow does nothing for the field next to the hedgerow. It's not mobile in the soil. Cover crops as mentioned above do help the field.

Comment: Books will tell you that marigolds have a funny smell that keeps insects away from neighboring plants. Maybe they have the pyrethrum of mums, but they don't help in the garden. Mixing the onion family into farm crops may protect them from grazing mammals like rabbits and deer.

Comment: @MackM, dude cover crops is exactly what I'm looking for. than you so much. please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: @YosefBaskin, Wow this looks interesting. I will definitely look this up. Thank you so much for your response.

Comment: Marigolds certainly do have an effect on *e.g.* tomato hornworm, but are "not a weed, they are a companion plant" and the effect is more reliable if they are among the tomatoes, not off at the edge of the field (they would also have a hard time growing under hedgerow plants)

Comment: @Ecnerwal Yup companion plants among crops, why not ?. thank you for your response.